# White space character escape in C#

Tags: c#, char

In C++, we know that to make a space we can use `\-30s` for making a white character in 30 space. In C#, we know that we can use `.padLeft` or `.padRight` to make a space too.

But I found that `.padLeft` or `.padRight` can't be used in the inside of `""`. For example: `console.Writeline(".padLeft")`. I've try to use `\s` too but it's still error:

[image]

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `@` before the start of your text (`string`).

Something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"\sBB|\tBA\tXi|\tFi|\tFkum|\tFiXi");
```

Comment: @YosuaChristianov It worked for me. Are you again getting the same errow which you got in the screenshot attached.